# RegEx Omits Leading Zeroes

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to write a relatively simply function in Python that parses phone number. At the moment, the RegEx is giving me trouble. Namely, it omits leading zeroes, which I would like to keep.

How can I modify it so the leading zeroes are kept? The pattern also keeps 4 items in the end, which is undesired. At most three digits in the last block are desired.

```
phone_number = re.sub("(\d{3})(?=(\d)+(?!\d))", r"\1-", "%d" % int(clean_number[:-1])) + clean_number[-1]
```

What I would like is something like this:

`Input: 00112223344`
`Output: 001-122-233-44`

Comment: If you don't want to strip leading zeroes, don't use `int`. This is nothing to do with the regex, they're gone before it gets there.

Comment: The regex isn't doing anything to leading zeros. `"%d" % int(...)` is discarding leading zeros.

Comment: Got it. What about the blocks of 4 at the end? How can I make sure that the last block on the right is at most 3 digits?

Comment: https://regex101.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
phone_number  = re.sub(r'(\d{3})', r'\1-', phone_number)
```

It should work.
Here is the [demo](http://ideone.com/rvfnYS)